# Azure DevOps pipeline conditions for source branch and build reason

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a multi-staged pipeline in which I want a specific stage's jobs only to run when a pull request is made to the Development branch.

The below YAML works yet the PS tasks are skipped even when I make a pull request to the Development branch. I also tried removing the source branch condition but to no avail.

```
trigger:
  - Development
  - Testing
  - Acceptance

stages:

  - stage: Development
    condition: and(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/Development'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
    jobs:
      - job: "FirstValidationJob"
        steps: 
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: 'Write-Host "Hello World!"'
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: 'Write-Host "Hi mom, this is me running PowerShell code on Azure!"'
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` of your PR, not the feature branch `Build.SourceBranch` which triggered the build.

```
condition: and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/Development'))
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that... thank you for the second pair of eyes!

Comment: hm, just replaced SourceBranch with TargetBranch but somehow the PS task is still skipped...

Comment: You observed, that the whole path of the variable changed, not only the last part? from `Build.SourceBranch`  to  `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services

Comment: Yeah, no matter what the PS task keeps getting skipped.

Comment: In this case I recommend a script task where you echo the single conditions. `-script: echo on & echo $(variables['Build.Reason'])` and so on

Comment: Are you on Azure DevOps Services or an On-Prem server (which one)?

Comment: this is on Azure DevOps

Comment: when I try to echo →  The term 'variables[Build.Reason]' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.

Comment: System.PullRequest.TargetBranch is not available in templates for Azure DevOps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services